# Are there any methods of testing how well a Gaussian Process fits your data?

Tags: regression, classification, normal-distribution, cross-validation, predictive-models

**Are there any methods of testing how well a Gaussian Process fits your data?**

I have been looking online and can not seem to find any statistical metrics that measure how well a Gaussian Process (Classification or Regression) fits your data.

[image]

The only thing which comes to mind is use Cross Validation (e.g. K-Fold, Leave One Out Cross Validation). For example:

- Split your data into 70-30 train-test
- Fit a Gaussian Process on the train set
- See how well the Gaussian Process performs on the test set (e.g. MSE, F-Score)
- Record the performance
- Repeat the first 3 steps many times and average the performance from each iteration.

Doing this would (in my opinion) would allow you to assess the Bias-Variance Tradeoff and Overfitting of the Gaussian Process Model.

But apart from Cross Validation: **Are there any methods of testing how well a Gaussian Process fits your data?**

Thanks!

Comment: Fitting a Gaussian process amounts to a linear regression model, and there are already methods of quantifying error, the R^2 is similar to the MSE. Splitting the sample can assess overfitting somewhat, but it can also reduce your power to detect/estimate effects. But it's funny because the question as stated "are there any methods of testing how well a Gaussian process fits your data" is much more than that: you might say a Gaussian process *doesn't* fit if the error distribution is double exponential. At its simplest, fit the regression, and plot the histogram of the errors.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I was really confused about this - I fit a gaussian process regression model to my data. apart from performance, how do i check how well it fits the data? (e.g. goodness of fit, aic, bic)